# Jmeter response in HTML view

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a script in jmeter but in the view results tree I am unable to response data in HTML view ,even after setting view HTML and HTML View modes.Please help me on this

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you see, can you attach a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (debugging proxy) if convinient.
Start Fiddler (listens 8888 port by default) and then start jmeter with command

```
jmeter -H localhost -P 8888
```

It shows full info about jmeter traffic